# What does page() do?

Tags: page.js

In the first example on https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/...

```
page('/', index)
page('/user/:user', show)
page('/user/:user/edit', edit)
page('/user/:user/album', album)
page('/user/:user/album/sort', sort)
page('*', notfound)
page() // what does this do?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page()` is equivalent to `page.start()`.

[source](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/issues/350#issuecomment-177326106)